# Oracle APEX - how to ensure callback finishes before the page is submitted

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have an interactive grid with a custom button. The button, when clicked, processes the selected rows:

loops through all selected rows and executes a callback for each row if the row meets a criteria.

```
apex.server.process
 ("process_selected_callback"
    ,{x01:$my_id}
    ,{type:'GET', dataType: 'text', success: function( text) {}}
 );
```

My callback contains basically this:

```
DECLARE
    l_my_id NUMBER;

BEGIN 
    l_my_id := TO_NUMBER(apex_application.g_x01);

    package1.my_process_record(l_my_id);
                    
END;
```

Every loop iteration when a row criteria is met, before executing the callback, a page item is incremented to get the count of records processed.
At the end of the loop I call apex.submit:

```
 apex.submit('DISPLAY_SUCCESS');
```

to call the process that grabs a page item containing count of records processed - `P1_RECORDS_PROCESSED` and uses `apex_application.g_print_success_message` to display a message to the user, stating how many records were processed.

Everything works fine but one issue - a lot of times `DISPLAY_SUCCESS` process gets executed before the callback and so the processed record count only gets incremented after the message is displayed. How can I ensure callback finishes before the page is submitted?

Perhaps there is a better way to process the selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you can do this.

**First Approach:**

Use Javascript Promises. Apex makes it easy for you since `apex.server.process` returns a `Promise` object.

Since you are looping through the rows and executing the callback for each row, you can just store the returned Promise from each `apex.server.process` call into an array and then use `Promise.all()` function to wait for all of the Promises to be resolved (AJAX requests to be finished), and then call `apex.submit('DISPLAY_SUCCESS');`. If any one of your AJAX calls might fail, you can use `Promise.allSettled()` instead of `Promise.all()`

You can refer to this to understand the `Promise.all()` function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

**Second Approach:**

The first approach seems inefficient. Do you really need to make an individual AJAX call for each row processed because it seems that all you are doing is just passing an ID to a Package function?

Why not run a loop and store all the IDs in an array and then do **JUST ONE** AJAX call and pass the array to it? The looping through the IDs can be done by your AJAX PL/SQL code which will not only be faster (presumably) but also more efficient for the browser as it doesn't have to run through multiple AJAX calls and all the associated overhead.

Comment: I actually already decided to put all IDs into an array and make a single call to pass those. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to call the "show_message" functionality in the callback function.

```
apex.server.process
 ("process_selected_callback"
    ,{x01:$my_id}
    ,{type:'GET',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function( text) {
        apex.submit('DISPLAY_SUCCESS');
      }
     }
 );
```

But the pitfall is that this will always submit the page when processing is done, regardless of any db errors that might occur. Since apex.server.process won't be triggered on DB errors, but just monitors whether the AJAX call has been succesfully executed.

To solve that issue, you can return a json object which holds the actual success result.

```
create or replace package1
  procedure my_process_record
  begin
    apex_json.open_object;

    << place the processing logic here >>

    apex_json.write('success', true);
    apex_json.close_object;
  exception
    when others then
      -- Free all output written so far
      apex_json.free_output;

      -- Create json error object
      apex_json.open_object;
      apex_json.write('success', false);
      apex_json.write('result' , sqlerrm );
      apex_json.close_object;
  end;
end package1;
```

The ajax call could then act on the returned result tag

```
apex.server.process
 ("process_selected_callback"
    ,{x01:$my_id}
    ,{type:'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function( json) {
        if ( json.hasOwnProperty("success") && json.success == true ) {
          apex.submit('DISPLAY_SUCCESS');
        }
        else {
          //Code to show the error
        }
      }
     }
 );
```

Hope this this and gives you a direction.

Comment: That solution would submit the page after processing each record. I need to first process all the records and only then submit the page